# OpenTelemetry .NET StartActiveSpan does not do anything while built-in spans are working

Tags: asp.net, .net, open-telemetry

I'm following the instructions [here](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/instrumentation/net/shim/) to add OpenTelemetry tracing into my web app. I'm calling `AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation` and `AddEntityFrameworkCoreInstrumentation`, both which seem to be working; I can see the HTTP handler and database level spans in my Trace (Using Google Cloud Trace View). However, when I try to create a trace span manually with  `tracer.StartActiveSpan("my-span");`, the span is not visible in the trace anywhere.

Here is my configuration code:

```cs
var serviceName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("K_SERVICE") ?? "web-ui";

builder.Services.AddOpenTelemetry()
    .ConfigureResource(resource => resource.AddService(serviceName))
    .WithTracing(
        tracing =>
        {
            tracing
                .AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation()
                .AddEntityFrameworkCoreInstrumentation(
                    e =>
                    {
                        e.EnrichWithIDbCommand = (activity, command) =>
                        {
                            var tag = string.Empty;
                            if (command.CommandText.StartsWith("--"))
                            {
                                using var reader = new StringReader(command.CommandText);
                                tag = reader.ReadLine()?[3..];
                            }

                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tag))
                            {
                                activity.SetTag("db.query.tag", tag);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                // Store the whole query for non-tagged queries.
                                activity.SetTag("db.query.command", command.CommandText);
                            }
                        };
                    });
            if (configuration.GetSection("Otlp").Exists())
            {
                tracing.AddOtlpExporter(e => configuration.GetSection("Otlp").Bind(e));
            }
        })
    .WithMetrics(
        metrics =>
        {
            metrics
                .AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation();
            if (configuration.GetSection("Otlp").Exists())
            {
                metrics.AddOtlpExporter(e => configuration.GetSection("Otlp").Bind(e));
            }
        });
builder.Services.AddSingleton(TracerProvider.Default.GetTracer(serviceName));
```

Here is my code to create a span (tracer is injected into the class):

```cs
using var span = tracer.StartActiveSpan(nameof(CreateMarkdownComment));
```

Answer (score 1):

I was missing some configuration lines:

```cs
tracing
 .AddSource(serviceName)
 .SetResourceBuilder(
     ResourceBuilder.CreateDefault()
         .AddService(serviceName: serviceName))
```

Adding these seemed to fix the issue.

Comment: You may want to look at the core getting started docs as that might give you information on why that part is important (it's to do with the fact that tracer's are defined by name, and must be added).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I thought that the `ConfigureResource(resource => resource.AddService(serviceName))` line basically applied that name to all telemetry by default and didn't know you have to define it specifically for tracing!